# Java socket port number changes on its own

Tags: java, sockets

#### Client

```
try {
    Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    System.out.println(sock.getLocalAddress());
    System.out.println(sock.getLocalPort());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeInt(55);
    ois.readInt();
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

#### Server

```
try {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
    Socket sock = ss.accept();
    System.out.println(sock.getLocalAddress());
    System.out.println(sock.getLocalPort());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

    System.out.println(ois.readInt());

    oos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

I run the server and then the client, in that order.
I pass 1234 as a command-line argument to the client. In other words, I execute threads this way

```
java server
java client 1234
```

Doing that prints these to the console

```
// server
/127.0.0.1
1224

// client
/127.0.0.1
50261
```

Neither threads move on from this point.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Java socket port number changes on its own

No it doesn't. You're looking at two different sockets and two different ports. A connection consists of two endpoints. The `localPort` of the client socket is 50261, which is the outbound port, and the `localPort` of the accepted socket at the server is 1234, which is the same as the port being listened at.

Have a look at the respective `getRemotePort()` values. You will see that the client's is 1234 and the server's is 50261, or rather that it agrees with the client's `localPort`, whatever it is next time you run it.

> Neither threads move on from this point. What's going on here?

You need to construct the `ObjectOutputStream` *before* the `ObjectInputStream`, for reasons explained in the Javadoc and in many answers here, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461894/objectinputstream-objectoutputstream-work-not-right/18462030?s=1|1.1109#18462030).